# Place character on chair from picture

Tags: edit-mode

can you can import a picture of a chair and import a 3d character made in blender and make it sit in the chair from the picture (like photoshop)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the fSpy software and addon but it won't help in every situation (if it's hard to find the vanishing lines, if the objects are not perpendicular, or aligned with each other, etc). What you can do is create a chair that looks roughly like the one of your picture, create a space that looks roughly like the one of your picture, put the camera in front of your scene:

[image]

Enable the *Lock Camera to View* option, select the camera, evaluate its *Focal Lens* from your picture, enable *Background Images*, select your image in order to always see it as a background when you are in camera view:

[image]

Put the chair where it is supposed to be, rotate it accordingly, move your camera until the 3D view matches the image perspective:

[image]

Now you roughly have the correct camera point of view, lock it, import your character, put its feet on the ground, hide the other 3D objects...

To render the scene with the picture as background you have different solutions, like using the *Compositor* to overlay the character on the background image.